# hasMany relation including null

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

**My setup :**

I have 2 models: `User` and `Setting`.

A user can have many settings:

```
public function settings(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Setting::class);
}
```

```
$user = User::with('settings')->find($id);
```

Here is the migration:

```
Schema::create('settings', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id')->primary();
    $table->uuid('user_id')->nullable()->index();
    $table->text('description');
    $table->string('setting_key');
    //$table->json('setting_value')->nullable();
    $table->text('setting_value')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

The `user_id` column is nullable because the `settings` table has default settings.

**My problem:**

I want to make it so that the `settings()` relation also returns rows where `user_id` is null (those are default settings, linked to no specific user).

**What I tried so far:**

This did not work:

```
public function settings(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Setting::class)->orWhereNull('settings.user_id');
}
```

This also did not work, even though the sql request in my debugbar seems fine:

```
$user = User::query()
    ->with([
        'settings' => function (HasMany $query) {
            $query->orWhereNull('settings.user_id');
        },
        // irrelevant stuff
    ])
    ->findOrFail($userId);
```

Which runs:

```
select * from `settings` where `settings`.`user_id` in ('123') or `settings`.`user_id` is null
```

No matter what, `$user->settings` is a Collection that does NOT contain any row from my `settings` table where `user_id` is null. It only contains rows where `user_id` equals the user's id.

Comment: Making code that always needs to check whether or not there is a user_id can become tiring when your application grows. Why not define a user_id 1 for the system?

Comment: Making code that always needs to check whether or not user_id equals 1 can become tiring when your application grows. Why not define a user_id null for the system?

Comment: It is generally easier to work with a default value than with nonexistent values ​​when it comes to the database. But it was just an idea ...

Comment: I don't think so. "null" is more semantic, it takes less disk/memory space, and it allows to keep foreign key constraints. Having to deal with "null" or "1" is the same in the end, but it's a treat when you have getter methods. Thank you for you suggestion but I believe that is out of the scope of my issue.

Comment: Why not just query the settings and then get the inverse relationship to users instead of querying users first and then settings. Because `hasMany` will not in any way return fields that does not have any identifier for relationship on the parent model that you're using which in this case is the `User` model.

Comment: @rkg Because that is not elegant. I prefer to send a single $user variable to my view, instead of sending both $user + $userSettings. I prefer to loop on $user->settings rather than $userSettings. Eager loading looks elegant to me and more compact within my controller. Indeed, the controller not only retrieves user settings, but also other user relations. I like to have 1 var ($user), instead of $userSettings + $userFriends + $userLikes + $userEtc...

Answer (score 0):

How about a merge of two results or raw expression?

I implement all your code and I could see the same difficulty... So I found these solutions not very elegant but functional.

**Alternative 1 - Merge results:**

```
//user
$u = DB::table('users')->join('settings', 'users.id', '=', 'settings.user_id')->get();
//settings without user_id
$n = DB::table('settings')->where('settings.user_id', '=', null)->get();
//all together
$result = $u->merge($n);
```

My output on php artisan tinker

```
>>> $result = $u->merge($n);
=> Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3019
     all: [
       {#3015
         +"id": "2",
         +"name": "name 123",
         +"email": "teste123@teste.com",
         +"email_verified_at": "2020-04-22 20:54:06",
         +"password": "1111111111111111111",
         +"remember_token": "1111111111111111111",
         +"created_at": "2020-04-22 21:13:50",
         +"updated_at": "2020-04-22 21:13:50",
         +"user_id": "123",
         +"description": "desc",
         +"setting_key": "conf",
         +"setting_value": "configuration-configuration",
       },
       {#3031
         +"id": "1",
         +"user_id": null,
         +"description": "desc",
         +"setting_key": "conf",
         +"setting_value": "configuration-configuration",
         +"created_at": "2020-04-22 21:13:50",
         +"updated_at": "2020-04-22 21:13:50",
       },
     ],
   }
```

**Alternative 2 - Raw Expression:**

```
$id = 123;

$r = DB::select(DB::raw("select * from settings where settings.user_id in ('{$id}') or settings.user_id is null"));
```

Comment: That is probably a valid/working approach but not elegant indeed. I would prefer to make it happen the "Laravel way", eager loading, and access relations through the $user variable: $user->settings, $user->friends, $user->likes, etc... Not $user, $userSettings, $userFriends, etc. I could tinker further with "setRelation()" on $user, but that would be even less elegant.

Comment: Yes, I understand you. Unfortunately, when we don't have time, we need not the best solution but a solution. But if you have time I encourage you to look for the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a *real* "Laravel way" solution, still allowing you to use the relation as usual.

```php
public function settings(): HasMany
{
    // Build a relationship, like usual
    $relation = $this->hasMany(Setting::class);

    // Add our custom constraint to the underlying query
    $query = $relation->getQuery();
    $query->orWhereNull($relation->getQualifiedForeignKeyName());

    // Still return the relationship, like usual
    return $relation;
}
```